# Why can't gnu make figure out this sequence of rules?

Tags: gnu-make

I have this `Makefile`:

```
%: %.x
    cp $< $@

build/%: src/%
    cp $< $@
```

And a directory structure that looks like this:

```
Makefile
build/
src/
    hello.x
```

Why does `make` behave as follows:

```
$ make build/hello
make: *** No rule to make target 'build/hello'.  Stop.
```

Why can't it see that

1. it can translate `src/hello.x` into `src/hello` using the first rule, and
2. copy `src/hello` into `build/hello` using the second rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Match_002dAnything-Rules), that is:

> If you do not mark the match-anything rule as terminal, then it is non-terminal. A non-terminal match-anything rule cannot apply to a file name that indicates a specific type of data. A file name indicates a specific type of data if some non-match-anything implicit rule target matches it.

Your first rule is a non-terminal match-anything rule, so it cannot apply to the target `src/hello` which indicates a specific type of data. Debug log with `make build/hello -d` also shows the process:

```
......
Considering target file `build/hello'.
 Looking for an implicit rule for `build/hello'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `hello'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `src/hello'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `hello'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `build/hello,v'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `hello'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `build/RCS/hello,v'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `hello'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `build/RCS/hello'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `hello'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `build/s.hello'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `hello'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `build/SCCS/s.hello'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `hello'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `src/hello'.
 Looking for a rule with intermediate file `src/hello'.
  Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `hello'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite `src/hello,v'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `hello'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite `src/RCS/hello,v'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `hello'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite `src/RCS/hello'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `hello'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite `src/s.hello'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `hello'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite `src/SCCS/s.hello'.
 No implicit rule found for `build/hello'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `build/hello'.
No need to remake target `build/hello'.
make: Nothing to be done for `build/hello'.
```

You should mark your first rule the match-anything rule as `terminal` by defining it with a double colon.

> When a rule is terminal, it does not apply unless its prerequisites actually exist. Prerequisites that could be made with other implicit rules are not good enough. In other words, no further chaining is allowed beyond a terminal rule.

Change your makefile to:

```
%:: %.x
        cp $< $@

build/%: src/%
        cp $< $@
```

Test with `make build/hello`:

```
cp src/hello.x src/hello
cp src/hello build/hello
rm src/hello
```

The debug log below shows how it works:

```
 ......
 Looking for a rule with intermediate file `src/hello'.
  Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `hello'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite `src/hello.x'.
 Found an implicit rule for `build/hello'.
   Considering target file `src/hello.x'.
    Finished prerequisites of target file `src/hello.x'.
   No need to remake target `src/hello.x'.
 Considering target file `src/hello'.
  File `src/hello' does not exist.
   Pruning file `src/hello.x'.
  Finished prerequisites of target file `src/hello'.
 Must remake target `src/hello'.
cp src/hello.x src/hello
Putting child 0x08a51438 (src/hello) PID 30908 on the chain.
Live child 0x08a51438 (src/hello) PID 30908
Reaping winning child 0x08a51438 PID 30908
Removing child 0x08a51438 PID 30908 from chain.
 Successfully remade target file `src/hello'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `build/hello'.
Must remake target `build/hello'.
cp src/hello build/hello
Putting child 0x08a51438 (build/hello) PID 30909 on the chain.
Live child 0x08a51438 (build/hello) PID 30909
Reaping winning child 0x08a51438 PID 30909
Removing child 0x08a51438 PID 30909 from chain.
Successfully remade target file `build/hello'.
Removing intermediate files...
rm src/hello
```